# Interpretation of glmmTMB with dispersion parameter in R

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I struggle with understanding the dispersion model and dispersion parameter of `glmmTMB` ,  and could not find answers on github,  in the vigniette or on stackexchange/stackoverflow.

I constructed a GLMM using `glmmTMB` with a dispersion paramenter to account for heteroscedastictity that is related to one of my predictors.

**Questions:**

1. I read on github or stackexchange, that the dispersion model was not constructed to be used with RE. Does anybody know whether that still up to date? Am I allowed to include a varying dispersion parameter to a model with a random effect? I need the random effect since I have repeated measures.
2. In my model I am interested in the three-way interaction term (of my three predictors) and wonder whether I can still interpret the conditional model the normal way. I usually investigate the model structure with summary(model). My dispersion model is highly significant, but I can`t find any explanation on how to interpret and deal with a dispersion model.
   I found a comment concerning this that confuses me: "When the same variables are in the conditional and dispersion models, the mean-variance relationship can be manipulated, but this could potentially lead to non-convergence issues." (from an R Journal Article of Brooks et al., 2017). ?sigma.glmmTMB says "nbinom2: returns an overdispersion parameter (usually denoted theta or k); in contrast to most other families, larger theta corresponds to a lower variance which is mu(1+mu/theta)." Since I do not understand what the dispersion parameter actually does, this information is not helpful.
   How do I have to adapt my interpretation of a model that includes a dispersion parameter with the package-built-in function `dispformula`

**Background information about my data and model:**

I was fitting a GLMM for a randomized controlled trial with repeated measures. It is assumed that the continous outcome (count data for psychopathologic symptom load) is influenced by time (3 time points: factor, 3 levels), treatment group  (factor, 2 levels) and occurence of certain events (factor, 2 levels) and their interactions. I fitted an glmer accordingly:
`glmer(outcome ~ time*group*event + (1| ID) , ... )`. With poisson distribution it was very overdispersed, and I therefore moved to a negative binomial model. Unfortunatly the plots of residuals (using `DHARMa`) revealed a pattern that suggested diverging variance with model preditions. Plotting predictor time against standardized residuals revealed heteroscedasticity. To account for the heteroscedastictidy, I moved to  constructing 4 different `glmmTMB` (because I have 4 outcomes) with dispersion parameter like so:

`m1 <- glmmTMB(outcome1 ~ event * time * group + (1|code), dispformula = ~time , family = "nbinom2", data = data_long)`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this a coding question (suitable for this site) or a statistics question.  If the later consider posting this question on CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com. Check out [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Peter. I will post it there since it is intertwined, Thak you also for the link on how to aks for guidance. I did not see this beforehand.